# Is there a way to show a message to specific users?

Tags: 8

I would like to programmatically set a message shown at least once for selected users or for all users with a specific role.

Comment: Do you prefer a back-end solution? 
Have you considered implementing this as a front-end library?
this is an open source project, [demo here](https://cookieconsent.insites.com/app/themes/insites-cookie-consent/examples/example-5-opt-in.html). 
If this is a viable solution then the question would become "how to attach a library to specific users?" and the answer is well documented [theme.api.php hook_page_attachments(array &$attachments)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.6.x)

Comment: I've great success with this: https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following snippet to your module, then you have to replace ***MODULE*** with your ***module machine name***

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $message = t("You have been served!");
        $request = \Drupal::request();
  $session = $request->getSession();
  $message_was_displayed = $session->get('mymodule_message_was_displayed', FALSE);
  if ($message_was_displayed === FALSE) {
    $messenger = \Drupal::messenger();
    $messenger->addMessage($message);
    $session->set('mymodule_message_was_displayed', TRUE);
  }
}
```